# Reporting Services publishing problems

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm having a problem in Visual Studio 2008 ASP.Net where I used the ReportWizard and created a bunch of Reports with .rdlc extensions, it also created a dataset for each report. In my page I use the "Microsoft Report Viewer", when I run the computer in my machine, the reports work. But when I use the option "Build->Publish" and someone on the same network as me, tries to use the page reports it says:

> Server Error - 404 File or directory
>   not found - The resource you are
>   looking for might have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve similar problem (worked on dev machine, but not web server) by using the info from http://forums.asp.net/t/1497749.aspx/1 .

In web.config, add the following under `<handlers>`

```
    <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd"
         path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"
         type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the published report. If yes, it is probably a rights issue, even though the error message is file not found.

Answer (score 0):

where are you publishing these files? remember that rdlc are designed to run on the client side this means the definition file and the dataset need to live on the client. if you want to use SSRS you need to specify RDL files and not RDLC